# Which servlet-api jar should I use for my cometd filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jetty, java-8, cometd

I am using cometd 3.0.1 and trying to deploy it in tomcat 7.0.50. I have some filter created, previously I was using jetty jar (9.2.2) to compile these filter classes, but after move from jetty which jar should I include in my class path.

I want jar so that I don't need to regenerate my war every time I move from one container to other.

Can I include servlet api jar directly from jdk (I am unable to find jar in my jdk). I am using java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation home page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) of Tomcat 7 says:

> Apache Tomcat version 7.0 implements the Servlet 3.0 and JavaServer Pages 2.2 specifications

So, you need the 3.0 version of the servlet API.

The Servlet API is not part of Java SE. It's part of Java EE. So you won't find it in the JDK. You only need the jar to compile your code.

Note that whether you use Jetty or Tomcat doesn't change anything: this jar is provided by the servlet container, so it must NOT be inside the war file. You can find the jar that Tomcat uses in the `lib` directory of Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. So even after using any container specify jar to compile my code I can use it with any container implementing same servlet version? In Java EE, where can I find this jar.

Comment: As long os you only use standard classes (i.e. classes from the java and javax packages, and not jetty classes), yes. Java EE is a specification. You can find this jar in tomcat/lib, as I said, or in Maven central.